# Is there a way to know which badges can be obtained more than once

Tags: support, badges

Is there a way to know which badges can be obtained more than once?

Answer (score 6):

[image]Yes it's written right there if you click on the badge:

Comment: Damn, I was 15 seconds behind you. Used a straight line; that was my mistake

Comment: @RichardTingle - rule one of images on Meta - freehand.

Comment: @RichardTingle what if I told you http://i.qkme.me/3v6f99.jpg

Comment: @Oded I'm assuming rule #2: red?  :P

Comment: @Doorknob - No. Rule #2 is: never talk about rule #1.